# Rendering a rails partial inside of another partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page listing many products, at taxons#show. Inside of taxons#show I'm rendering the partial _products.html.erb to display the products, images, variants, etc. By default, when you click an individual product on taxons#show rails redirects you to the products#show page where the partial _cart_form.html.erb is rendered which displays add to cart options.

However, I'm trying to render _cart_form.html.erb inside a lightbox in _products.html.erb, which is inside of taxons#show. My problem is that _products.html.erb is using

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
```

to display each individual product. And _cart_form.html.erb is using @product to display all of its product info. If I keep it this way I get a NoMethod error for nilClass because @product isn't defined.

Then I tried:

```
<% @product = product %>
<%= render 'spree/shared/cart_form' %>
```

But because this is above the code that outputs all of the products on taxons#show it changes every product inside _product.html.erb to the same product, the first one listed.

How can I render _cart_form.html.erb inside of a lightbox for each individual product?

Here's taxons_controller.rb:

```
  def show
  @taxon = Taxon.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
  return unless @taxon

  @taxon_id = params[:id].split('/').first
  if @taxon_id 
    instance_variable_set "@enable_#{@taxon_id}", true   #big lettered taxonomy heading
  end

  @product_type = params[:id].split('/').last
  @featured = @taxon_id + '/' + @product_type            #featured image     


  @searcher = Spree::Config.searcher_class.new(params.merge(:taxon => @taxon.id))
  @searcher.current_user = try_spree_current_user
  @searcher.current_currency = current_currency
  @products = @searcher.retrieve_products

  @related_products = @taxon.products.offset(rand(Spree::Product.count - 7)).limit(7)

  respond_with(@taxon)
```

And products_controller.rb:

```
  def show
  return unless @product

  @variants =    @product.variants_including_master.active(current_currency).includes([:option_values, :images])
  @product_properties = @product.product_properties.includes(:property)

  referer = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
  if referer
    begin
      referer_path = URI.parse(request.env['HTTP_REFERER']).path
      # Fix for #2249
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      # Do nothing
    else
      if referer_path && referer_path.match(/\/t\/(.*)/)
        @taxon = Taxon.find_by_permalink($1)
      end
    end
  end

  respond_with(@product)
end
```

Comment: <%= render 'spree/shared/cart_form' :locals => {:product => product }%> doesn't work?

Comment: I get a NoMethod error: undefined method 'has_variants?' for nil:NilClass